# ASP Classic Friendly URLs via Custom Error Pages

Tags: asp-classic, seo, friendly-url

I want to beautify my URLs and make them SEO-friendly.

I've encountered numerous methods doing so including several IIS modules, and creating a custom error page with a response.transfer redirect to "original" url (http://evolt.org/search_engine_friendly_urls_with_iis_and_classic_asp/)

I've actually implemented the last method and it works well, but I want to ask:
Isn't it problematic SEO-wise to lead the user/search-engine to a semi error page?

I mean, doesn't it have a bad effect on search engines?

Thanks!

P.S. The code on the custom error page looks like this

```
<%
strQuerystring = Mid(Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING"),12)
aParameters = Split(strQuerystring,"/")
On Error Resume next

Server.Transfer("/"&aParameters(1) & ".asp")

If Err Then
Response.Status = "404 Not Found"
Server.Transfer("/error/real-404-page.asp")
End If
%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the page you're transferring the request to will return an HTTP `200 OK` status, the search engine crawler has no way to know that internally you used this 'hack' to support friendly URLs.

Comment: Thank you! That's all I needed to know.